# error could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.vs'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, installshield-2010

i created a program in visual studio 2010 using c# and sql server as database and used installshield for setup package everything works fine and can be installed completely

however when i open program it gives this error

```
could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.vs' version=10.0.0...
```

i referenced to microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks in visual studio and copied microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.dll file from developer pc to pc that program installed on it but still give same error

please help